# Pivot with multiple columns and Count

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, transform

Pretty new to SQL and completely lost at the moment. I have a table looking like this:

```
 AccountNr  |     Year1     |    Year2
-----------------------------------------
       121  |      New     |      N/A
       131  |   Recurring  |      New
       116  |   Recurring  |     Recurring
       123  |    Inactive  |     Recurring
       112  |   Invactive  |     Inactive
```

so simply showing the account status of a customer in given years. What I need is a count of how many New, Inactive, Recurring and N/A accounts I have in Year1, Year2 and all the following periods. Ideally I would like it to look something like this:

```
Status      |   Year1      |   Year2 
-----------------------------------------
      New   |      1       |      1
 Recurring  |      2       |      2
 Inactive   |      2       |      1
   N/A      |      0       |      1
```

Doesn't have to look exactly like this, it just has to count how many accounts there are for each status in each year. I am using MS Access by the way.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this consistently in MS Access with a single query.  For your particular data, you can do:

```
select y2.status, nz(y2.year1, 0) as year1, y2.year2
from (select t.year2 as status, count(*) as year2
      from t
      group by t.year2
     ) as y2 left outer join
     (select t.year1 as status, count(*) as year1
      from t
      group by t.year1
     ) as y1
     on y1.status = y2.status;
```

This works because all the statuses are in the `year2` column.

If you have a separate table of statuses, you can do:

```
select s.status, nz(y2.year1, 0) as year1, nz(y2.year2, 0) as year2
from statuses as s left outer join
     (select year2 as status, count(*) as year2
      from t
      group by year2
     ) as y2
     on y2.status = s.status left outer join
     (select year1 as status, count(*) as year1
      from t
      group by year1
     ) as y1
     on s.status = y1.status;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for your reply.Tried the code (edited to fit my data) and it is now asking me to enter parameter values for C_1.Comp1_PY and the status colum gives out a count with the same values as CY_Comp1

This is the code:

select C_1.status, nz(C_1.Comp1_PY, 0) as Comp1_PY, C_1.CY_Comp1
from (select CY_Comp1 as status, count(*) as CY_Comp1
      from Account_Churn
      group by CY_Comp1
     ) as C_1 left outer join
     (select Comp1_PY as status, count(*) as Comp1_PY
      from Account_Churn
      group by Comp1_PY
     ) as C_2
     on C_2.status = C_1.status;

Comment: @Simon . . . There are no parameters in this query.  That can occur because of a typo when you write the query.

Comment: . . Yes, I found the typo, thanks. However I have three columns now: "Status" "Cy_Comp1" and "Comp1_PY" and the last one seems to be giving out correct values, however the "Status" column gives out counts instead of terms such as "New" and the second column only shows 0 as values

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem. Where you wrote "select year2 as status, count(*) as year2 from t" it apparently needed to be "select t.year2 as status, count(*) as year2 from t" because it was just selecting the counted column twice. Anyhow, this fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Simon . . . Wow.  That is subtle.  I wasn't even thinking that the status column and the count column could have the same name . . . and in this example they do.